# Camel - How to stop route execution on exception?

Tags: apache-camel

Is there any way I can stop the route execution (after displaying a log message) when exception is caught?

```
        <doTry>
            <process ref="messageProcessor"/>
            <doCatch>
                <exception>java.lang.IllegalArgumentException</exception>
                <log message="some message related to the exception" />
            </doCatch>
        </doTry>
```

Please provide a way to achieve this in Spring DSL. I've already tried < stop/> but that doesn't display log message.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Added a process in doCatch which stop's a Camel context.

```
        <doTry>
            <process ref="messageProcessor"/>
            <doCatch>
                <exception>java.lang.IllegalArgumentException</exception>
                <handled>
                    <constant>true</constant>
                </handled>
                <setHeader headerName="exceptionStackTrace">
                    <simple>${exception.stacktrace}</simple>
                </setHeader>
                <process ref="mandatoryParameterIsNull"/>           
            </doCatch>
        </doTry>
```

Processor:

```
@Component
public class MandatoryParameterIsNull implements Processor{

Logger log = Logger.getLogger(MandatoryParameterIsNull.class);

@Override
public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {

    if (log.isDebugEnabled()) {
        log.debug("Some parameter is mandatory");
        log.debug(exchange.getIn().getHeader("exceptionStackTrace"));
    }
    exchange.getContext().getShutdownStrategy().setLogInflightExchangesOnTimeout(false);
    exchange.getContext().getShutdownStrategy().setTimeout(60);
    exchange.getContext().stop();
}
}
```

Comment: Did you ever find a solution in Java DSL?

Answer (score 5):

There are many ways to approach this. In addition to the accepted answer you may also want to use one of the following:

```
onException(SomeException.class)
.log("Uh oh...")
.stop()
```

within your DSL

or:

```
exchange.setProperty(Exchange.ROUTE_STOP, Boolean.TRUE);
```

within your Processor()

Have a look at the official documentation on this topic here: http://camel.apache.org/intercept.html

Comment: A global scope `onException()` (outside any route) with a producer (`log(...)`) creates an extra route and the `stop()` in it stops just this error handling route itself, not the route in which the exception was thrown originally.

Answer (score 0):

If you create a OnException Route?
Like this:

```
onException(Exception.class)
        .log("YOUR LOG EXCEPTION");

from("direct:start")...
```

Comment: Some explanations about this piece of code would probably be beneficial.

Comment: Sorry for this, I wrote quickly.
If you use the route OnException, you create a generic exception for all your route errors, so if you need just stop your execution, I believe this is the best way to log something and stop your route.

Comment: Just for rememember, OnException route is a normal route, so you can use a process or a bean if you want.

Answer (score 0):

Stops the route current execution, but the route still listening
`route.onException(Throwable.class).process(ThrowableProcessor.NAME).handled(true);`

Answer (score 0):

The above answers show you how to handle the exception. But, to stop the route from throwing exception specify :

```
?throwExceptionOnFailure=false
```

in the URI.

example :

```
.to(http://localhost:8000/4d-analytics-mock-service/iso/retrieve?throwExceptionOnFailure=false)
```